Sign in with Apple - account delete with Swift
I am currently working on a Swift application whose data storage and authentication part is managed by Firebase. I would like to offer my users the possibility of using their Apple account for account creation.
To do this I added Apple as a “Connection Provider” in the Firebase console settings.
This part works without problem, when the user clicks on the “Sign in with Apple” button a popup appears asking if they agree to share this information (first and last name / email address) for account creation.
Sign In With Apple confirmation popup
After entering the password, the user is authenticated and their account is created on Firebase.
Firebase users
If I go to the iPhone settings in the Connection and Security section > Sign in with Apple, I can see my app in the list.
Sign in with Apple on iPhone
Now my problem is at the time of deleting the user's account. When the account is deleted it no longer exists in Firebase as we expected.
An email is also sent by Apple to warn that the application has revoked the account that had been created with “Sign in with Apple”.
Apple email for account revocation
And the application no longer appears in the list of applications in the Connection and Security > Connection with Apple from iPhone section.
However, when I click on the “Sign in with Apple” button again, I don’t see the window that asks me if I want to share my connection information. The app behaves as if I was simply logged out but when I enter my iCloud password I am logged in except in reality it is a new account.
 When I look in Firebase I have a new id for my user.
Firebase users with a new id for my user
In addition, the user is not really connected to the application since certain views behave as if the user session was empty. The only way is to erase the emulator and make a new build.
I need help finding what's not working in my current code because I've been going around in circles for several days and I really don't understand what's going on.
Here my entire AuthenticationViewModel:
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
import CryptoKit
import AuthenticationServices

@MainActor
class AuthenticationViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var userSession: FirebaseAuth.User?
    @Published var user: User?
    @Published var isBadCredentials: Bool = false
    @Published var isEmailNotVerified: Bool = false
    @Published var errorMessage = ""

    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    private var currentNonce: String?

    init() {
        Task {
            await fetchUser()
        }
        verifySignInWithAppleAuthenticationState()
    }
}

// MARK: - Email and Password Authentication
extension AuthenticationViewModel {

    func fetchUser() async {
        guard let uuid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

        // get in users collection the document corresponding to the uuid
        guard let snaphsot = try? await Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(uuid).getDocument()
        else {
            return
        }
        // decode snaphot data into the currentUser
        self.user = try? snaphsot.data(as: User.self)
        self.userSession = Auth.auth().currentUser
    }

    func signIn(withEmail email: String, password: String) async throws {
        do {
            let result = try await Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password)

            // check if user has activated their account
            if result.user.isEmailVerified {
                self.userSession = result.user
                await fetchUser()
            } else {
                isEmailNotVerified = true
            }
        } catch {
            isBadCredentials = true
            print("Failed to sign in with error \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    func signOut() {
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut() // signs out user on backend
            self.userSession = nil // wipes out user session and go back to LoginView
            self.user = nil // wipes out current user data model
        } catch {
            print("Failed to sign out with error \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    func deleteAccount() async -> Bool {
        guard let user = userSession else { return false }
        guard let lastSignInDate = user.metadata.lastSignInDate else { return false }
        let needsReauth = !lastSignInDate.isWithinPast(minutes: 5)

        let needsTokenRevocation = user.providerData.contains { $0.providerID == "apple.com" }

        do {
            if needsReauth || needsTokenRevocation {
                let signInWithApple = SignInWithApple()
                let appleIDCredential = try await signInWithApple()

                guard let appleIDToken = appleIDCredential.identityToken else {
                    print("Unable to fetdch identify token.")
                    return false
                }
                guard let idTokenString = String(data: appleIDToken, encoding: .utf8) else {
                    print("Unable to serialise token string from data: \(appleIDToken.debugDescription)")
                    return false
                }

                let nonce = randomNonceString()
                let credential = OAuthProvider.credential(withProviderID: "apple.com",
                                                          idToken: idTokenString,
                                                          rawNonce: nonce)

                if needsReauth {
                    try await user.reauthenticate(with: credential)
                }
                if needsTokenRevocation {
                    guard let authorizationCode = appleIDCredential.authorizationCode else { return false }
                    guard let authCodeString = String(data: authorizationCode, encoding: .utf8) else { return false }

                    try await Auth.auth().revokeToken(withAuthorizationCode: authCodeString)
                }
            }
            //try await TokenRevocationHelper().revokeToken()
            try await user.delete()
            signOut()
            errorMessage = ""
            return true
        } catch {
            print(error)
            errorMessage = error.localizedDescription
            return false
        }
    }

    func deleteAccountWithRevocationHelper() async -> Bool {
        do {
            // add code to find out if the user is connected to SiwA
            try await TokenRevocationHelper().revokeToken()
            try await userSession?.delete()
            return true
        }
        catch {
            errorMessage = error.localizedDescription
            return false
        }
    }
}

extension Date {
    func isWithinPast(minutes: Int) -> Bool {
        let now = Date.now
        let timeAgo = Date.now.addingTimeInterval(-1 * TimeInterval(60 * minutes))
        let range = timeAgo...now
        return range.contains(self)
    }
}

// MARK: Sign in with Apple
class SignInWithApple: NSObject, ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate {

    private var continuation: CheckedContinuation<ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential, Error>?

    func callAsFunction() async throws -> ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential {
        return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            self.continuation = continuation
            let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
            let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
            request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]

            let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
            authorizationController.delegate = self
            authorizationController.performRequests()
        }
    }

    func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
        if case let appleIDCredential as ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential = authorization.credential {
            continuation?.resume(returning: appleIDCredential)
        }
    }

    func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithError error: Error) {
        continuation?.resume(throwing: error)
    }
}

class TokenRevocationHelper: NSObject, ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate {

    private var continuation : CheckedContinuation<Void, Error>?

    func revokeToken() async throws {
        try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            self.continuation = continuation
            let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
            let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
            request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]

            let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
            authorizationController.delegate = self
            authorizationController.performRequests()
        }
    }

    func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
        if case let appleIDCredential as ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential = authorization.credential {
            guard let authorizationCode = appleIDCredential.authorizationCode else { return }
            guard let authCodeString = String(data: authorizationCode, encoding: .utf8) else { return }

            Task {
                try await Auth.auth().revokeToken(withAuthorizationCode: authCodeString)
                continuation?.resume()
            }
        }
    }

    func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithError error: Error) {
        continuation?.resume(throwing: error)
    }
}

//MARK: Sign in with Apple
extension AuthenticationViewModel {

    func handleSignInWithAppleRequest(_ request: ASAuthorizationAppleIDRequest) {
        request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
        let nonce = randomNonceString() // prevents replay attack by generate a nonce
        currentNonce = nonce
        request.nonce = sha256(nonce)
    }

    func handleSignInWithAppleCompletion(_ result: Result<ASAuthorization, Error>) {
        if case .failure(let failure) = result {
            errorMessage = failure.localizedDescription
        } else if case .success(let authorization) = result {
            if let appleIDCredential = authorization.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential {
                guard let nonce = currentNonce else {
                    fatalError("Invalid state: a login callback was received, but no login request was sent.")
                }
                guard let appleIDToken = appleIDCredential.identityToken else {
                    print("Unable to fetdch identify token.")
                    return
                }
                guard let idTokenString = String(data: appleIDToken, encoding: .utf8) else {
                    print("Unable to serialise token string from data: \(appleIDToken.debugDescription)")
                    return
                }

                let credential = OAuthProvider.credential(withProviderID: "apple.com",
                                                          idToken: idTokenString,
                                                          rawNonce: nonce)
                // Sign in
                Task {
                    do {
                        let result = try await Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential)
                        self.userSession = result.user

                        guard  let email = appleIDCredential.email else { return }
                        guard let fullName = appleIDCredential.fullName else { return }

                        //TODO: create a function for create User document
                        do {
                            let user = User(id: result.user.uid, fullName: "\(fullName.givenName ?? "") \(fullName.familyName ?? "")", email: email)
                            let encodedUser = try Firestore.Encoder().encode(user)
                            try await Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(user.id).setData(encodedUser)
                        } catch {
                            print("Failed to create user with error \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        }
                    }
                    catch {
                        print("Error authenticating: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func verifySignInWithAppleAuthenticationState() {
        let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
        let providerData = Auth.auth().currentUser?.providerData
        if let appleProviderData = providerData?.first(where: { $0.providerID == "apple.com" }) {
            Task {
                do {
                    let credentialState = try await appleIDProvider.credentialState(forUserID: appleProviderData.uid)
                    switch credentialState {
                    case .authorized:
                        break // The Apple ID credential is valid.
                    case .revoked, .notFound:
                        // The Apple ID credential is either revoked or was not found, so show the sign-in UI.
                        self.signOut()
                    default:
                        break
                    }
                } catch {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential {
    func displayName() -> String {
        return [self.fullName?.givenName, self.fullName?.familyName]
            .compactMap( {$0})
            .joined(separator: " ")
    }
}

private func randomNonceString(length: Int = 32) -> String {
    precondition(length > 0)
    let charset: [Character] =
    Array("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-._")
    var result = ""
    var remainingLength = length

    while remainingLength > 0 {
        let randoms: [UInt8] = (0 ..< 16).map { _ in
            var random: UInt8 = 0
            let errorCode = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 1, &random)
            if errorCode != errSecSuccess {
                fatalError(
                    "Unable to generate nonce. SecRandomCopyBytes failed with OSStatus \(errorCode)"
                )
            }
            return random
        }

        randoms.forEach { random in
            if remainingLength == 0 {
                return
            }

            if random < charset.count {
                result.append(charset[Int(random)])
                remainingLength -= 1
            }
        }
    }
    return result
}

private func sha256(_ input: String) -> String {
    let inputData = Data(input.utf8)
    let hashedData = SHA256.hash(data: inputData)
    let hashString = hashedData.compactMap {
        String(format: "%02x", $0)
    }.joined()
    return hashString
}

Thanks.
